# JavaCV: convert array of integer to Mat

Tags: java, opencv, javacv

I am trying to implement face recognition in my photo database using JavaCV. While detecting possible faces works fine (there are a lot of examples for Java already), I am stuck at doing the actual recognition. To be more precise, at training the face recognizer.

For testing purposes I have a folder structure with a subfolder per known person labeled "s" + id, in which the training photos are located. What works is reading the images and adding them to an array. What does not work is creating a second array with the identifiers. LBPHFaceRecognizer.train does require a Mat and I cannot figure out how to create the required data structure. What I have so far is:

```
MatVector images = new MatVector();
List<Integer> ids = new ArrayList<Integer>();
File root = new File("orl_faces/");
for (File subFolder : root.listFiles()) {
    if (subFolder.getName().matches("s\\d+") && subFolder.isDirectory()) {
        int personId = Integer.parseInt(subFolder.getName().substring(1));
        for (File file : subFolder.listFiles()) {
            if (file.getName().endsWith(".pgm") && !"10.pgm".equals(file.getName())) {
                IplImage img = cvLoadImage(file.getAbsolutePath());
                images.put(img);
                ids.add(personId);
            }
        }
    }
}

// ---- FIXME here is where I am stuck ----
Mat labels = new Mat(new Size(ids.size(), 1));
for (int i = 0; i < ids.size(); i++) {          
    MatExpr m = Mat.ones(new Size(1, 1), CV_32SC1);
    Mat m2 = m.asMat();
    labels.push_back(m2);
}

model.train(images, labels);
```

When executing this, I get a

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.RuntimeException: vector<T> too long
    at org.bytedeco.javacpp.opencv_face$FaceRecognizer.train(Native Method)
```

and obviously even if it did work, I still would not have my numbers in there. Any help is greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `MatOfInt` and an array of ints. For example, if you collect labels in `List<Integer`:

```
        int[] allLabels = new int[labels.size()];
        for (int i = 0; i < labels.size(); i++) {
            allLabels[i] = labels.get(i);
        }
        faceRecognizer.train(faces, new MatOfInt(allLabels));
```

This should work :)